# Dropdown list overlapping on nested elements

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a nested drop down list on my page and I encountered a problem of overlapping different elements from different list category, I can go down the list with 2 elements only, the third element will open another list, this is the link to my page its under the brand section: [www.in2info.com/pamco](http://www.in2info.com/pamco)

I'm not using any scripting on it, it is all css
Please test it and help me find the problem.

Regatds,
G

Comment: Don't know the problem, but please note that with those CSS menus it's difficult for users to select something in the submenu. When the user tries to move sideways to the submenu, he will almost always have to move *diagonally*, causing some other submenu to open.

Comment: And to allow people to figure out this problem you should try to reproduce it with a minimal example, and add the code of that example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a z-index problem

```css
 /*remove this*/
#cssmenu ul ul {
    z-index: 5000;
}

/*add something like this*/
.has-sub-r-l:hover > ul {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeH - It appears that you implemented this answer on your website. Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: @GeorgeH - It would be courteous to mark this as an accepted answer so that others do not spend their time trying to solve a problem that has already been solved.